# How does tm interface with snow?

Tags: r, tm, snow

The high-performance task view notes that `tm` can use snow for parallel text mining ([High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)). However, I have not found any examples demonstrating how this can be done, although I have found some discussion of parallel computing with `tm` ([R/Finance 2012](http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2010/Theussl+Feinerer+Hornik.pdf)). Could anyone shed some light on how `tm` interfaces with a cluster created by `snow`?

EDIT: See the comment by BenBarnes below. Specifically:

> According to `?tm_startCluster`, that function looks for an MPI cluster (not a SOCK cluster) and "allow[s] 'tm' to use a cluster". Perhaps that would be an alternative to hadoop, since, given a few prerequisites, `snow` can set up an MPI cluster.

Answer (score 1):

LMGTFY using "r-project tm parallel" as search strategy produces this as the third hit:

[Distributed Text Mining with tm](http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2010/Theussl+Feinerer+Hornik.pdf)

Copying directly from the slides:
Solution: 
1. Distributed storage 
  Data set copied to DFS (‘DistributedCorpus’) 
  Only meta information about the corpus remains in memory 
2. Parallel computation 
  Computational operations (Map) on all elements in parallel 
  MapReduce paradigm 
  Work horses tm_map() and TermDocumentMatrix() 
Processed documents (revisions) can be retrieved on demand.

Implemented in a “plugin” package to tm: tm.plugin.dc.

```
#Distributed Text Mining in R 
> library("tm.plugin.dc") 
> dc <- DistributedCorpus(DirSource("Data/reuters"), 
                          list(reader = readReut21578XML) ) 
> dc <- as.DistributedCorpus(Reuters21578) 
> summary(dc) 
#A corpus with 21578 text documents 
#The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame 
#Available tags are: 
#create_date creator 
#Available variables in the data frame are: 
#MetaID 
--- Distributed Corpus --- 
#Available revisions: 
#20100417144823 
#Active revision: 20100417144823 
#DistributedCorpus: Storage 
#- Description: Local Disk Storage 
#- Base directory on storage: /tmp/RtmpuxX3W7/file5bd062c2 
#- Current chunk size [bytes]: 10485760 
> dc <- tm_map(dc, stemDocument)
> print(object.size(Reuters21578), units = "Mb") 
#109.5 Mb 
> dc 
#A corpus with 21578 text documents 
> dc_storage(dc) 
DistributedCorpus: Storage 
- Description: Local Disk Storage 
- Base directory on storage: /tmp/RtmpuxX3W7/file5bd062c2 
- Current chunk size [bytes]: 10485760 
> dc[[3]] 
#----------
Texas Commerce Bancshares Inc 
' 
s Texas 
Commerce Bank-Houston said it filed an application with the 
Comptroller of the Currency in an effort to create the largest 
banking network in Harris County. 
The bank said the network would link 31 banks having 
13.5 billion dlrs in assets and 7.5 billion dlrs in deposits. 
Reuter 
#---------
> print(object.size(dc), units = "Mb") 
# 0.6 Mb
```

Further searching useing the terms: tm, snow ,parLapply ... [produces this link:](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920021421/snow/parlapply.R)

With this code:

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeCluster(4, type="SOCK")

par(ask=TRUE)

bigsleep <- function(sleeptime, mat) Sys.sleep(sleeptime)
bigmatrix <- matrix(0, 2000, 2000)
sleeptime <- rep(1, 100)

tm <- snow.time(clusterApply(cl, sleeptime, bigsleep, bigmatrix))
plot(tm)
cat(sprintf("Elapsed time for clusterApply: %f\n", tm$elapsed))

tm <- snow.time(parLapply(cl, sleeptime, bigsleep, bigmatrix))
plot(tm)
cat(sprintf("Elapsed time for parLapply: %f\n", tm$elapsed))

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: They touch on it in one line of one slide, so not quite what I'm looking for. However, I may just end up using hadoop.

Comment: Nowhere in that code is there any mention of the snow library or sending functions to a SOCK cluster. What you copied directly from the slides refers to MapReduce.

Comment: @TimothyP.Jurka, according to `?tm_startCluster`, that function looks for an MPI cluster (not a SOCK cluster) and "allow[s] 'tm' to use a cluster". Perhaps that would be an alternative to hadoop, since, given a few prerequisites, `snow` can set up an MPI cluster.

Comment: DWin, the "tm" variables in that example refer to "time" not the tm package. That example doesn't use the tm package at all. Ben Barnes provided what I was looking for: the specific interface between snow and tm. I'm not sure how I missed that in the documentation. Thank you Ben!